# Variable number of arguments in Haxe

Tags: parameters, haxe

I'm looking for a way to do something like this in Haxe:

```
function foo(...args)  
{  
  for (arg in args)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Someone around here who can help me?

Comment: You can't pass in an array or object? In the manner you specify, type safety and stuff would be lost.

Comment: Yeah! i think that's the closest and simplest way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing list of arbitrary function arguments in Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386594/passing-list-of-arbitrary-function-arguments-in-haxe)

Answer (score 4):

This question is very old, so, I'm answering as a documentation.
Rest arguments are supported in Haxe since 4.2:

```
function logAll(...arguments : String)
{
   for(arg in arguments)
      trace(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Haxe doesn't have rest arguments, mostly because those are untyped by nature, and the language should help going typed to have safest code. Typed code can be checked and also optimized by the compiler. More errors compile-time, less errors run-time.

Still the same result of rest arguments can be somehow achieved in a few ways, depending on what you are looking for; does the function only receive values or also objects?

The most straightforward way is using the `Any` type and `Reflect`:

```
function loop(props:Any) 
{
    for (prop in Reflect.fields(props))
    {
        trace(prop, Reflect.field(props, prop));
    }
}
// usage: 
loop({name: "Jerson", age: 31});
```

You can just use an array with values, therefore you also need to use an array when you use it:

```
static function loop(values:Array<Any>) 
{
    for (i in 0...values.length)
    {
         trace(i, values[i]);
    }
}
//usage:
loop(["Jerson", 31]);
```

If you dislike this array in the implementation, you can also use this wonky function, which I wouldn't advice, but just to give an idea.

```
function loop<A,B,C,D,E,F>(?prop1:A, ?prop2:B, ?prop3:C, ?prop4:D, ?prop5:E, ?prop6:F) 
{
    var props:Array<Any> = [prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4,prop5,prop6];
    for (i in 0...props.length)
    {
         trace(i, props[i]);
    }
}
// usage: 
 loop3("Jerson", 31);
```

Try these examples here: https://try.haxe.org/#Be3b7

There are also [macros for rest arguments](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-rest-argument.html), which can be nice if you are familiar with macros. Note that this will trace while compiling and doesn't generate the trace in the output source at the moment.

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;

macro static function loop(e1:Expr, props:Array<Expr>)
{
    for (e in props) 
    {
        trace(e);
    }
    return macro null;
}
// Usage:
loop("foo", a, b, c);
```

Best advice of course is just don't go dynamic much to keep type-safety, but this should keep you going.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The array solution it helps me. I'm implementing a keyboard input manager, and I need to do something like:

`Keyboard.bind("jump", Key.UP, Key.W);`

just for a better read. But writing:

`Keyboard.bind("jump", [Key.UP, Key.W]);`

is the closest way to do it.

Comment: I'd certainly use an array in that case. Arrays already have an API and tools to work with them.

Comment: @JersonLaTorre I would probably use a macro for this.

Comment: Using the macro approach, how could you restrict the rest params to a single type, i.e, `Int`s? How to fail with a compile error if the expr is not of the type you expect?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to, there's a way: [`Reflect.makeVarArgs`](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#makeVarArgs).  This is heavily untyped, so I recommend that you consider using a typed alternative first.

Personally, I would probably only use this for debugging or in code that's already untyped for some other reason.

Example:

```
static function _foo(args:Array<Dynamic>)
{
    return "Called with: " + args.join(", ");
}

static var foo:Dynamic = Reflect.makeVarArgs(_foo);

[...]

trace(foo(1));
trace(foo(1, 2));
trace(foo(1, 3, 3));
```

*([see it in Try Haxe](https://try.haxe.org/#C56bA))*

Comment: A generic version of `makeVarArgs` would be nice for cases where the rest of the params follow the same type. I.e if `_foo` accepted an array of `Int`s only.