# Haxe - variable number of arguments in SWC

Tags: actionscript-3, arguments, haxe

I am porting a library from AS3 to Haxe and I need to make a method accepting variable number of arguments. Target is a *.swc library.

My question relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465215/variable-number-of-arguments-in-haxe/) but none of the suggested solutions outputs a method with the required signature: `someMethod(...params)`

Instead, the produced method is: `someMethod(params:*=null)`

This won't compile in AS3 projects using the library and the used code is beyond my reach. Is there a way to do this, perhaps macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's a great question.  And, it turns out there is a way to do it!

Basically, [`__arguments__`](http://old.haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic#avm1-and-avm2-flash-magic) is a special identifier on the Flash target, mostly used to access the special local variable [`arguments`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html).  But it can also be used in the method signature, in which case it changes the output from `test(args: *)` to `test(...__arguments__)`.

A quick example ([live on Try Haxe](https://try.haxe.org/#3231e)):

```
class Test {
    static function test(__arguments__:Array<Int>)
    {
        return 'arguments were: ${__arguments__.join(", ")}';
    }
    static function main():Void
    {
        // the haxe typed way
        trace(test([1]));
        trace(test([1,2]));
        trace(test([1,2,3]));

        // using varargs within haxe code as well
        // actually, just `var testm:Dynamic = test` would have worked, but let's not add more hacks here
        var testm = Reflect.makeVarArgs(cast test);  // cast needed because Array<Int> != Array<Dynamic>
        trace(testm([1]));
        trace(testm([1,2]));
        trace(testm([1,2,3]));
    }
}
```

Most importantly, this generates the following:

```
static protected function test(...__arguments__) : String {
    return "arguments were: " + __arguments__.join(", ");
}
```